# GridLines not showing in a GridView with CSS reset?

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

I have a page which includes a css reset.  On that page, I have a gridview with the GridLines="Both" property set to true, but the grid lines are not appearing.  If I remove the css reset, the gridlines show up.  This is only happening in IE.  I want the reset and I want the gridlines to appear.  Does anyone know the solution to this?

Comment: Inspect the GridView's applied styles with something like Firebug and then add them to your CSS file explicitly.

Comment: In other words, inline styling will not work is what you are saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to call the stylesheet or style defining the gridlines appearing *after* you've called the reset stylesheet.

Failing that makes sure that there isn't a more-specific selector defined in the reset stylesheet, that's overriding the element styles for which you want gridlines to appear. There's also nothing stopping you defining the gridlines *in* the reset-stylesheet, just as a check to see where the overriding style's being defined.

But, as noted in Jab's comment to your question, using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) would be the fastest way to see where the styles are coming from. If you're using IE then, assuming you're on IE8, you can use [Firebug too](http://elegantcode.com/2008/03/06/ie-team-ports-firebug-to-ie8/), albeit they're calling it [Developer Tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/03/07/improved-productivity-through-internet-explorer-8-developer-tools.aspx).